# SQL Previous currency rate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to ask you for help with getting previous currency rate.
Eg. I have two tables (`Orders` and `CurrencyRates`) which I want to join. First table encloses orders in EUR, and second encloses currency rate from EUR to USD.

[image]

I would like to join it by Order Date. The problem is with order date "10.11.2018" which has null rate from `CurrencyRates` table. I would like to have here value from previous day rate (in this case "09.11.2018). And for the future date ("18.11.2018") I would like to have value having max(Date) from `CurrencyRates` table. Is there any way to join it to have expected values?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross apply`:

```
select o.*, cr.date, cr.rate, cr.currency
from orders o cross apply
     (select top (1) cr.*
      from currencyrates cr
      where cr.date <= o.orderdate
      order by cr.date desc
     ) cr;
```

Comment: It was so obvious... It means I have to learn a lot. Thank you very much. This is answer which I expected.

Comment: @NewSQLGuy . . . This is actually not *obvious*.  `Cross apply` implements lateral joins, which I would consider to be a rather advanced feature in SQL.

Comment: I mean I should know this. Anyway thank you one more time.